# CSS div cut off screen by margin-left - need scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, margin

I have a div that has `top:50%; left:50%;` and also has a margin-left of some value (usually negative).

When the browser window is re-sized, the edge of the div can get cut off. Is there any easy way to easily add in a scrollbar when this happens?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t3sqeceL/1/)

Comment: add `margin-left: -100px;` only not `400px`. by the way .. whats the motive behind adding negative margin?

Answer (score 0):

Since your element has `position absolute`, it is cut out off the normal page rendering flow, so there is not way to add a scrollbar without JavaScript.

Comment: is there anything I can change position: absolute; to that will allow me to achieve my goal?

Comment: if you do that, than position of your element will change, because top and left propperies will no longer be applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left: -100px;` only instead `margin-left: -400px;` to appear div in center.

Answer (score 0):

change your css with the following one:

```
.overflowing {
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

i hope this would help you.